# jquery and form.submit - slow and not working in all browsers

Tags: jquery, forms

This is probably a very easy question but I am just learning jquery and I'm probably making a very beginner mistake. I set up validation on a basic order form, but when I attempt to use the submitHandler:  to submit the form, some browsers hang and do nothing, while others churn for a minute or 2 and then do actually submit. Here is the jquery script bit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function () { $("#order").submit(); }
});
$().ready(function () {

   // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#order").validate({
        rules: {
            lastname: "required",
            firstname: "required",
            confirm_email: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#email"
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
            domain: "required",
            selpackage: "required"
  //       agree: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your first name",
            lastname: "Please enter your last name",
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                equalTo:   "Passwords do not match"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            confirm_email: "Email addresses do not match"
//         agree: "Please accept our policy"
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

The form name is order, and it is just a regular  tag. Could someone point me in the right direction?